# MS Access VBA/SQL - Select Distinct matching records from 3 tables and update a single column

Tags: sql, vba, database, ms-access, select

I've been struggling with this for a few days now and I'm at my wit's end.

I have 3 datasets that need comparing - the first table with a list of Part_ID's, and then two other datasets ('dataTables') that may/may not contain those same ID's (the corresponding column exists in these two tables, but the value may not).

I need to look at each value in table 1 (lets call it keyTable), see if it exists in either of the dataTables, and then if there's a match, grab the value from a column within the dataTables, called 'Definition' and stick it in a column called 'def_exists' in the keyTable on the same row as the Part_ID.

I've tried various SQL queries, with DISTINCT and nested SELECT functions and haven't had any success. I was able to match the Part_ID fields from keyTable with one of the dataTables and append the 'Definition' value properly, but I couldn't remove duplicates, and since there is a one-to-many relationship between the Part_ID and Definition in the dataTable, I ended up with over a million duplicates (keyTable is ~16k records, Query returned ~1.6m). Trying to Query all three tables at once ended up with 125m+ records.

I hope an example of what I'm trying to achieve will make this a bit easier to understand since it probably sounds a bit vague or confusing.

keyTable

```
ID    Part_ID    Random_Info    Def_Exists_1    Def_Exists_2
1     ABC123     Bla            
2     BCD234     Bla
3     CDE345     Bla
4     DEF456     Bla            
5     EFG567     Bla
6     FGH678     Bla
```

dataTable1

```
ID    Part_ID    Definition
1     ABC123     A1
2     ABC123     A2
3     ABC123     A3
4     ABC123     A4
5     BCD234     B1
7     BCD234     B2
8     BCD234     B3
9     CDE345     C1
10    CDE345     C2
```

dataTable2

```
ID    Part_ID    Definition
1     DEF456     D1
2     DEF456     D2
3     DEF456     D3
4     EFG567     E1
5     EFG567     E2
6     EFG567     E3
7     FGH678     F1
8     FGH678     F2
9     FGH678     F3
```

Desired Output
keyTable

```
ID    Part_ID    Random_Info    Def_Exists_1    Def_Exists_2
1     ABC123     Bla            A1
2     BCD234     Bla            B1
3     CDE345     Bla            C1
4     DEF456     Bla                            D1
5     EFG567     Bla                            E1
6     FGH678     Bla                            F1
```

I hope the example tables make it a bit more clear. If there are multiple matches, i.e D1, D2, D3 for DEF456, I'd like only the first record to show, or even just a 'YES' in plain text.

I also need the 'YES' or Definition to be shown in the correct column, i.e. dataTable1 = Def_Exists_1, dataTable2 = Def_Exists_2.

Any help would be great, I feel like I've scoured the web for solutions and nobody has a clue - either that or my SQL is still rusty (which is quite likely).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with subqueries

```
select kt.*,
       (select top (1) as definition
        from datatable1 dt1
        where dt1.part_id = kt.part_id
       ) as definition_1,
       (select top (1) as definition
        from datatable1 dt2
        where dt2.part_id = kt.part_id
       ) as definition_2
from keytable as kt;
```

Note that this returns an arbitrary matching definition.  You can specify which definition -- such as the first -- by including an `order by` in the subqueries -- such as `order by id`.

Comment: I've tried the below code, with Siemens_BOM_Summary, IMS1_CODAC and IMSA_CODAC as keyTable, dataTable1 and dataTable2 respectively; and Component_Number/Part_No as the part_ID for the BOM_Summary and IMS tables respectively.

`SELECT BOM.*,
(SELECT TOP (1) AS Definition FROM IMS1_CODAC ims1
WHERE ims1.Part_No = BOM.Component_Number As Exists_IMS1,
(SELECT TOP (1) AS Definition FROM IMSA_CODAC imsa
WHERE imsa.Part_No = BOM.Component_Number As Exists_IMSA
FROM Siemens_BOM_Summary AS BOM;`

Where Exists_IMSx = definition_x

It throws the error: 'Syntax error' for the first SELECT TOP 1